# How to Fix all kind of Harddisk Errors?

Tags: 12.04, installation, hard-drive

How can I fix all kind of Harddisk errors ? Because I have a Ubuntu PC and I want to install one more separate flavour of Ubuntu for testing purpose but its keeping giving me an error like file system having errors.

In the live mode I have tried like

```
sudo fsck -y /dev/sda9
```

I mean my drive letter and in the later try ,again the same error came up & I am tired with many number of trails.

EDIT:[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your hard disk has errors, you need to buy a new hard disk, or get the one you have replaced under warranty, if it is under warranty. No software can fix mechanical problems with the disk.

Comment: Exactly. *Disk* errors can't be solved by filesystem checks or other software approaches.

Comment: I have updated with more information.

Comment: @gertvdijk I think I should give up then , because I dont have single $.

Answer (score 0):

some errors can be fixed. if the mag on the disk has faded, repeatedly writing to it can re mag the sector. how ever if it is physical damage, then it can't be repaired. it is marked as bad, and not used.this is not a problem, unless the bad sector is in a critical area, ie the boot, partition, fat sectors.